# Major Ember upgrade - 1.12 to 3.5

Tags: javascript, cordova, ember.js, ember-cli

In nearest future I will be doing a serious update of the application. I have a little experience with ember.js & have no one who can help me resolving this matter. The app is written in ember 1.12, and there are few dependencies. It has a web version and mobile (iOS+Android) written in cordova - all of them need an upgrade.

What kind of problems should I expect? 
How to prepare for them? 
How much time should I estimate? 
Any help will be very useful- it's first time when I will be doing app upgrade.

I have checked this links, but most of them are for above 2.0 versions.

https://www.emberscreencasts.com/meta_guide_to_upgrading_ember
https://medium.com/ingenious/how-to-upgrade-ember-js-to-3-x-and-live-to-fight-another-day-cfc28c16b726
http://www.ember-cli-diff.org/
https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/everything-you-need-to-know-to-upgrade-your-ember-js-app-including-ember-3-9de5e808dde0
https://medium.com/ember-ish/upgrading-ember-from-1-13-to-2-8-0-f1dbcecc40ca
https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/how-to-use-ember-2-code-in-your-ember-3-app-9ed15c28bad6

Comment: You might want to consider hiring someone for the task, that being said take a look at [the deprecation](https://emberjs.com/deprecations/) section on the ember website and make sure you tackle all deprecations before moving on to the next major version, maybe try upgrading from LTS to LTS, going all the way from 1.12 to 3.5 is not going to be straight forward.

Comment: The important question is if you're already using ember-cli. Maybe also checkout the ember discord channel.

Comment: No, I haven't using ember-cli in this project. I believe that when ember 1.12 came out, embec-cli wasn't a thing. I want to add it when I upgrade app. Also hiring someone isn't an option for me.

Comment: As @Lux indicated, the ember discord channel will be useful.  Lot's of experience to answer questions.  An additional resource is the [release posts](https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/13/ember-1-12-released.html) as they talk about the changes to each release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded a bunch of Ember apps / addons from 1.11 -> 2.18 in advance of the 3.0 release. I don't think there was a single minor version upgrade until the 2.10s that didn't break my app.

I also simultaneously upgraded ember cli with the app. I tried upgrading ember cli to the latest, but I had a bunch of cryptic errors and reached a sort of dead end. What I instead opted for was looking back at the Ember release notes and seeing which version of ember cli was the latest at the time of the Ember release. I would upgrade Ember cli every 4 versions or so, unless if I encountered issues at which point I would immediately upgrade.

The single most important thing is automated tests. I see that you say you have no tests and will just manually test but this is foolish. I had a bunch of code that I needed to upgrade that had no tests. I wrote comprehensive tests over the course of a week since I had two weeks to do the upgrade. These were absolutely vital and some upgrades would break 60-80% of my tests. It would have taken me 2 months without tests probably, but I accomplished it in 2 weeks with the tests, using the first to write the needed extra tests.

Comprehensive tests are best, but far from necessary. At the minimum I would recommend you take the time to mock your API calls and write an acceptance test for each page of your app that serves as a smoke test. The test is as simple as go to the url and check the dom is there. [Ember cli page object](http://ember-cli-page-object.js.org/docs/v1.14.x/) helps immensely + html5 `test-*` data classes.

Once you've done that, follow what @Trenton Trama suggested. Upgrade minor version, run tests, fix problems, rinse and repeat until fully upgraded.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the size of your application and how extensive your test suite is, you'll probably be dedicating a minimum of 4 weeks getting just the web version up to 3.5.

The process will be time consuming and tedious.
1. Upgrade by 1 minor version (1.12->1.13)
2: Run your test suite and fix any issues that come up
3: Manually test the tool by navigating around & fix any issues that come up
4: During the testing, you should have identified a handful of deprecations.  Fix those.
5: Repeat steps 1-4
6: After you've upgraded to 2.0.0, you may be able to skip a couple of minor versions at a time, if you aren't using private APIs and your dependencies are small.

Ember maintains their [changelog](
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) as well as a page that lists [deprecations and their solutions](https://emberjs.com/deprecations/), so you'll want to become buddies with the version you're upgrading to.  For each deprecation they mention, check the linked issue history to see what the suggested replacement is.   Be proactive - don't wait until the final version to fix a deprecation.

The big/common issues you'll encounter are:
Views are deprecated and removed.  You'll need to understand how components work and migrate any existing views to a component.
The select helper gets removed.
If your views & components use targetObject to get the controller, you'll need to make them work without doing it.  This means determining what properties & actions need to be passed in and explicitly doing it.  Components shouldn't know anything about what called them.

Ember has a solid guide on working with deprecations at https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/handling-deprecations/ that may be of some help.

Keep your changes versioned.  You'll break something bad enough that it's easier to just roll back and try again.  If you're not using versioning, you're in for a really hard time.
Finally, make sure you clean out your npm directory between versions & wipes - If you don't, you may thing everything is working, but it really isn't.

As Patsy commented - You're probably better off hiring someone who knows ember very well to do this upgrade.  If you don't know ember very well, you may be putting fixes in that back you into a corner.

Comment: I think going from one minor version to the next one might only be needed for 1.12 -> 1.13, 1.13 -> 2.0. I would expect that upgrading from one LTS to the next one is fine afterwards. If the application isn't having much dependencies and isn't using a lot of private APIs, I would even give a direct upgrade from 2.0 to 2.18 a chance. Skipping some minor versions might prevent you from facing bugs in ember.js / ember-data that have been fixed later and only been backported to LTS.

Comment: Those are two big ifs - and I've seen a lot of older ember code samples that suggest using private apis, so I lean toward the side of not getting lucky. 
You brought up a good point about skipping a few minor versions to avoid bugs that had to be patched later.

Comment: Thx for your comments! Unfortunately, the app does not have any suit test, so I'll do the tests manually. I think upgrading 1 LTS version at a time is the best approach. Of course, I will keep the entire process versioned. The information about deprecated and removed views was very helpful to me. Once again - thank you!

Comment: @akurek I would recommend to write acceptance tests before doing this. Otherwise you will waste a lot of time on manual testing.

Comment: Once you get to about 2.12, ember-cli-update is a great help for upgrading.  I believe it can do upgrades and code-mods rom 2.9 onward. Even if you're only going to bump a couple versions, it does the grunt work.  Then you fix what needs to be fixed